# SQL query to fetch data from last visit of particular column

Tags: sql

I have a table where columns are regno,dt,visitno and symptom_code. I'd like to fetch data from last visit of regno. Please suggest SQL query.

Comment: Post correct table structure, with sample data and sample output and post your code you have tried so far

Comment: and also tell the DBMS which you are using?

Comment: and also what have you tried. your sample code , atleast.

Answer (score 2):

Every DBMS supports this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab AS t1
WHERE dt =
 ( SELECT MAX(dt) FROM tab AS t2
   WHERE t1.regno = t2.regno)
```

Most DBMSes support Windowed Aggregate Functions, easier to write and usually more efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 ( SELECT ...
     ,RANK() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY regno
            ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rnk
    FROM tab
 ) AS dt
WHERE rnk = 1
```